# SQL Same ID Populated in Multiple Rows with Different Column Values Populated--Need One ID in One Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like following:

```
ID     Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
001     A       
001             B   
001                     C     
001                              D
002             X
002                              Y
```

I want the result like the following:

```
ID    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
001    A       B       C       D
002            X               Y
```

The challenge is the number of columns is unknown, maybe this it has a Col5 or even Col10.
Any thoughts? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select id, max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2, max(col3) as col3, max(col4) as col4
from t
group by id;
```

This assumes that there are no duplicates within a column for an id.

For additional columns, you would need to add additional clauses to the `select` statement.

Comment: Thanks! But what if I have 20 other columns, I would have to do Max(col1) all the way to Max(col20) and group by ID?

Comment: Thanks Gordon, although it is not scalable, it works fine. :D